# Which bootstrap gem is better for rails 3.2.12 app with javascript & css?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

When searching rails bootstrap gem, there are likely more than one results. Like:

```
https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails
http://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrapped-rails
https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass
```

railscasts.com showcased twitter-bootstrap-rails. Bootstrap-sass has the most downloads. However this one seems go along with the sass and we are using js & css in our application. If we are using javascript & css, which bootstrap gem is a better fit? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the official bootstrap gem uses Less for CSS and the last one uses SASS for CSS. The choice of LESS or SASS has no effect on javascript that decision only effects stylesheets.  All of them are compatible with JavaScript.

I use bootstrap-sass because I prefer SASS to LESS and ruby on rails is configured to use sass/scss out of the box which is why it has more downloads.

Comment: Also we use css for stylesheets. Do we have to use sass for bootstrap-sass?

Comment: No, the bootstrap styles will be written in sass inside the gem, but regular css will work perfectly fine for your styles. You can even override the sass styles in the gem with your own custom css.

Answer (score 1):

I ve always preferred `https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails` since it is easy to install and as john said that it does not have any effect with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I also go along with John. SASS is Rails' out of the box solution - I like to keep implementations as close to the standard approach as possible ... unless there are compelling reasons to do it differently.

Moved one project to that approach - really like the combination.

All the best ...